# TCP, HTTP and the Multi-Threading Sweet Spot

Tags: perl, multithreading, http, tcp, network-programming

**I'm trying to understand the performance numbers I'm getting and how to determine the optimal number of threads.**

**See the bottom of this post for my results**

I wrote an experimental multi-threaded web client in perl which downloads a page, grabs the source for each image tag and downloads the image - discarding the data.

It uses a non-blocking connect with an initial per file timeout of 10 seconds which doubles after each timeout and retry.  It also caches IP addresses so each thread only has to do a DNS lookup once.

The total amount of data downloaded is 2271122 bytes in 1316 files via 2.5Mbit connection from http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/npp/all/hires/true/ .  The thumbnail images are hosted by a company which claims to specialize in low latency for high bandwidth applications.

Wall times are:

> 1 Thread takes 4:48 -- 0 timeouts
>   2 Threads takes 2:38 -- 0 timeouts
>   5 Threads takes 2:22 -- 20 timeouts
>   10 Threads take 2:27 -- 40 timeouts
>   50 Threads take 2:27 -- 170 timeouts

In the worst case ( 50 threads ) less than 2 seconds of CPU time are consumed by the client.

avg file size   1.7k
avg rtt         100 ms  ( as measured by ping )
avg cli cpu/img 1 ms

The fastest average download speed is 5 threads at about 15 KB / sec overall.

The server actually does seem to have pretty low latency as it takes only 218 ms to get each image meaning it takes only 18 ms on average for the server to process each request:

0   cli sends syn
50  srv rcvs syn
50  srv sends syn + ack
100 cli conn established / cli sends get
150 srv recv's get
168 srv reads file, sends data , calls close
218 cli recv HTTP headers + complete file in 2 segments MSS == 1448

I can see that the per file average download speed is low because of the small file sizes and the relatively high cost per file of the connection setup.

What I don't understand is why I see virtually no improvement in performance beyond 2 threads.  The server seems to be sufficiently fast, but already starts timing out connections at 5 threads.

The timeouts seem to start after about 900 - 1000 successful connections whether it's 5 or 50 threads, which I assume is probably some kind of throttling threshold on the server, but I would expect 10 threads to still be significantly faster than 2.

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT-1**

Just for comparisons sake I installed the DownThemAll Firefox extension and downloaded the images using it.  I set it to 4 simultaneous connections with a 10 second timeout.  DTM took about 3 minutes to download all the files + write them to disk, and it also started experiencing timeouts after about 900 connections.

I'm going to run tcpdump to try and get a better picture what's going on at the tcp protocol level.

I also cleared Firefox's cache and hit reload.  40 Seconds to reload the page and all the images.  That seemed way too fast - maybe Firefox kept them in a memory cache which wasn't cleared?  So I opened Opera and it also took about 40 seconds.  I assume they're so much faster because they must be using HTTP/1.1 pipelining?

**And the Answer Is!??**

So after a little more testing and writing code to reuse the sockets via pipelining I found out some interesting info.

When running at 5 threads the non-pipelined version retrieves the first 1026 images in 77 seconds but takes a further 65 seconds to retrieve the remaining 290 images.  This pretty much confirms [MattH's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267781/matth) theory about my client getting hit by a `SYN FLOOD` event causing the server to stop responding to my connection attempts for a short period of time.  However, that is only part of the problem since 77 seconds is still very slow for 5 threads to get 1026 images; if you remove the `SYN FLOOD` issue it would still take about 99 seconds to retrieve all the files.  So based on a little research and some `tcpdump`'s it seems like the other part of the issue is latency and the connection setup overhead.

Here's where we get back to the issue of finding the "Sweet Spot" or the optimal number of threads.  I modified the client to implement HTTP/1.1 Pipelining and found that the optimal number of threads in this case is between 15 and 20.  For example:

> 1 Thread takes 2:37 -- 0 timeouts
>   2 Threads takes 1:22 -- 0 timeouts
>   5 Threads takes 0:34 -- 0 timeouts
>   10 Threads take 0:20 -- 0 timeouts
>   11 Threads take 0:19 -- 0 timeouts
>   15 Threads take 0:16 -- 0 timeouts

There are four factors which 
affect this; latency / rtt , maximum end-to-end bandwidth, recv buffer size
and the size of the image files being downloaded.  [See this site for a
discussion on how receive buffer size and RTT latency affect available
bandwidth](http://www.cachefly.com/research_performance.html).

In addition to the above, average file size affects the maximum per connection
transfer rate.  Every time you issue a GET request you create an empty gap in
your transfer pipe which is the size of the connection RTT.  For example, if 
you're Maximum Possible Transfer Rate ( recv buff size / RTT ) is 2.5Mbit and 
your RTT is 100ms, then every GET request incurs a minimum 32kB gap in your
pipe.  For a large average image size of 320kB that amounts to a 10% overhead
per file, effectively reducing your available bandwidth to 2.25Mbit. However,
for a small average file size of 3.2kB the overhead jumps to 1000% and
available bandwidth is reduced to 232 kbit / second - about 29kB.

***So to find the optimal number of threads:***

> Gap Size = MPTR * RTT
>   MPTR / (MPTR / Gap Size + AVG file size) * AVG file size)

For my above scenario this gives me an optimum thread count of 11 threads, which is extremely close to my real world results.

If the actual connection speed is slower than the theoretical MPTR then it
should be used in the calculation instead.

Comment: Are you sure your client isn't limiting itself to two concurrent HTTP sessions (causing client #3 to wait for client #1/#2 to finish)? This is, after all, what some HTTP RFCs suggests clients *should* do. And if not, are you sure the *server* (or something along the way) doesn't do this? Ie. can you verify the simultaneousness of your sessions?

Comment: @bzlm:  I wrote the client from scratch, I don't use any libraries.  So I'm pretty close to 100% sure the connections are concurrent from the client side.  I suppose I could you tcpdump to see when I recv SYN's from the server although I don't know if that's sufficient.

Comment: @hobbs:  How could Perl threading be at fault?  Total cpu time for the process is under 2 seconds.

Comment: If used right, perl threads are NOT the cause of this.

Comment: I have seen some servers with limits on concurrent access from the same IP.  It may be that you are hitting a limit like that.  You can check for this by trying to download content from some other sites.

Comment: I fail to see what CPU time has to do with anything.

Comment: @Eric Strom:  Yeah, I'm just having trouble finding sites that have 1000+ images on a single page with image tags and not flash or something weird like that.

Comment: @Robert => you could see what kind of rates some of the batch image download addons for firefox can get from that site.  I believe there are a few that you can set the number of concurrent downloads.

Comment: @Robert If you download something like Google's start page instead of some images, do the results differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please correct me this summary is incorrect:

- Your `multi-threaded` client will start a thread that connects to the server and issues just one `HTTP GET` then that thread closes.
- When you say 1, 2, 5, 10, 50 threads, you're just referring to how many concurrent threads you allow, each thread itself only handles one request
- Your client takes between 2 and 5 minutes to download over 1000 images
- Firefox and Opera will download an equivalent data set in 40 seconds

I suggest that the server rate-limits http connections, either by the webserver daemon itself, a server-local firewall or most likely dedicated firewall.

You are actually abusing the webservice by not re-using the HTTP Connections for more than one request and that the timeouts you experience are because your `SYN FLOOD` is being clamped.

Firefox and Opera are probably using between 4 and 8 connections to download all of the files.

If you redesign your code to re-use the connections you should achieve similar performance.

Comment: @MattH: +1 In general, I suspect that you're correct about the timeouts being do to a firewall perceiving a `SYN FLOOD`.  However, I would disagree with your point about abuse for two reasons.  The `HTTP/1.1` standard **does not** require clients to support persistent connections.  Clients have the option of using the `Connection: close` header. Second, the site lists all 1300+ thumbnails on a single web page.  If you're not prepared to serve that many images to a single client over non-persistent connections then break it up into multiple pages.  I will likely try persistent connections.

Comment: @MattH:  There is a thread pool of N threads, each thread has exactly one TCP connection open at a time for N concurrent TCP connections.  Pipelining is not currently used, so each connection is used to download one file.

Comment: @Robert: You don't have to be malicious in order to abuse something. You don't have to be a network analyst or a server administrator in order to put up a webpage with a thousand images on it. HTTP 1.1 spec says that implementations `SHOULD` implement persistence. Opening a thousand connections per minute to a webserver is inefficient (as you've discovered while asking this question) and still IMO abusive. Your assertion that "hosting page with 1300 images" implies "the server MUST support 1300 simultaneous connection attempts from a single host" won't hold with any server administrators.

Comment: You make a reasonable point.  I'm still trying to understand more specifically what's happening, and right now I'm actually suspecting that due to the small file sizes and the connection setup overhead that I'm suffering from tinygrams eating my bandwidth.

Comment: You where most correct on your answer.  Take a look at my summary of results if you're interested.